# Fatal error: Class 'Lanot_EasySticker_Helper_Data' not found in /public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

Tags: magento-1.7

I am getting the following error (except a different class each time applicable to the extension) every time I try to install an extension: Fatal error: Class 'Lanot_EasySticker_Helper_Data' not found in /home/aaadmin/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546. I have seen it on the dashboard, and in some modules- not til accessing the configuration area. This is the part in Mage.php that reads the following:

```
 /**
     * Retrieve helper object
     *
     * @param string $name the helper name
     * @return Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
     */
    public static function helper($name)
    {
        $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
        if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
            $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
            self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
        }
        return self::registry($registryKey);
    }
```

If it's a permission issue. I haven't seemed to be able to figure it out. Please advise.

Comment: Does file `Helper/Data.php` exist in the extension? is it readable by the web-server? if it exists, what operating system are you using so we can help with the permissions?

Comment: I give my folders a 755 and my files a 644. It is a Linux server. The files all seem to be there!

Comment: Are you fixing the permissions again for the module after you are installing them? Since only the modules are broken, it can't be a problem with the other part of magento or else it would be broken as a whole since the core uses that function heavily.

Comment: I had compilation on I think that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package on Magento Connect seems to work just fine.  I tested it against 1.7.0.2.

Since you said you had compilations turned on, disable that, clear your cache and try again.

Afterward, rerun your compilation.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the class exists:
If it doesn't create it:
File: `app/code/local/Lanot/EasySticker/Helper/Data.php` with this content

```
<?php
class Lanot_EasySticker_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
}
```

Comment: The files are there that's the weird part